# ¿Cómo hacer correctamente SCHTASKS a un computador remoto o mejor al que no tengo acceso?

Tags: python, windows, cmd, batch, exe

[OBJETIVOS]

1 Ejecutar un script completo en cualquier otro equipo sin tener que programar la tarea uno a uno sino que mas bien un archivo haga ese trabajo por mi

2 Bueno la idea es que mi script se ejecute completo a determinada hora o al iniciar windows bueno cualquiera de las dos y había oído que con un archivo bat se lograba esto así que...

estoy intentando esto:

```
schtasks /Create [/S <system> [/U <username> [/P [<password>]]]]
[/RU <username> [/RP <password>]] /SC <HOURLY> [/MO <HOURLY:4 hours>] [/D <day>]
[/M <months>] [/I <idletime>] /TN <Ejemplo> /TR <C:\Users\PERSONAL\Desktop\Vivete\Imagen2.py> [/ST <9:30>]
[/RI <interval>] [ {/ET <endtime> | /DU <duration>} [/K] [/XML <xmlfile>] [/V1]]
[/SD <startdate>] [/ED <enddate>] [/IT] [/Z] [/F]
```

Es la primera vez que hago un archivo .bat, cualquier recomendación que puedan hacer se las agradezco. También quiero saber si ya quedo la tarea programada en windows si hay otra forma más fácil o mejor de programar una tarea en windows de manera remota es decir para cualquier otro computador por favor avísenme.

**(PS) Cuando digo remoto no me refiero a un computador al que puedo acceder sino a cualquier computador que descargue mi programa**

Comment: TIenes un archivo ```.bat``` o un ```.exe```?

Comment: guarde el script como bat y dentro de el le pedi que programara una tarea que es un exe pero alli figura como .py porque todavia no hago el exe

Comment: Puedes usar un *.py* sin problemas, no es necesario que sea un *.exe*. En Windows tienes una cosa que se llama **programador de tareas**. Si tienes derechos de administración del equipo es fácil poder programar algo desde ahí de manera visual.

Comment: pero quiero programar una tarea para un computador remoto es decir para los usuarios de mi programa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438020/how-to-start-a-python-file-while-window-starts) respuesta (en inglés) hay algunos tips que me parecieron bastante acertados. Agrego algunas cosas.

Dependiendo de lo que haga el script podés:

1. empaquetarlo como un servicio, después instalarlo
2. agregarlo en el RUN del registro (HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run)
3. agregar un acceso directo en la carpeta Inicio del menú de inicio. Suele cambiar de lugar dependiendo de la versión del Windows (Típicamente %ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Menú Inicio\Programs\Startup ó %ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Start Menu\Programs\Startup para la versión en inglés ó %ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Menú Inicio\Programas\Inicio en Windows XP)
4. usar el programador de tareas: podés crear la tarea con el asistente del programador de tareas para que inicie el script ya sea en el inicio o cada un cierto período de tiempo o también la podés crear para que se ejecute a petición y llamarla con SCHTASKS /run /tn "nombre_de_la_tarea" desde otro script con alguna de las soluciones anteriores.

La solución depende de lo que necesites o lo que haga el script. Tomando nota de las siguientes diferencias:

- La solución 1 ejecuta el script al inicio de la PC (mientras que las soluciones 2 y 3 lo hacen cuando el usuario se loguea)
- La solución 2 está un poco más "escondida" para el usuario, mientras que la solución 3 le deja más control a este para deshabilitarlo.
- La solución 1 necesita permisos de administrador, mientras que las otras dos pueden ser realizadas por cualquier usuairo.
- La solución 4 muestra una ventana CMD.

En mi caso, para que no muestre la ventana CMD, lo que hice fue un pequeño EXE en Visual Basic con un Process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden

Comment: estoy verificando para ver si tengo problemas luego califico

Comment: bien quisiera saber como agregarlo en el RUN del registro (HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run) porque como comente en la pregunta es la primera vez que se me ofrece hacer este tipo de cosas

Comment: quisiera un paso a paso mas detallado de la solución número 2

Comment: Según los cambios que acabo de ver en la pregunta también podría ser factible crear un instalador por ejemplo con InnoSetup que instale ya sea el programa empaquetado como servicio o que cree la tarea programada. Editado: También serviría para crear la entrada en el registro (solución 2).

Comment: ok podrias darme una idea de como hacer eso

Comment: Según [esto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12250151/how-to-add-a-scheduled-task-with-inno-setup) `Filename: schtasks.exe; Parameters:" /create /tn "ESS pushdata" /tr {app}\pushdata.exe /sc daily "` deberías poder crear la tarea programada desde el tag RUN del script del InnoSetup. Tendrías que jugar un poco con el programa. [Acá](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rr6G7GU52Wc) te dejo un pequeño ejemplo que encontré de cómo hacer un instalador personalizado.

Comment: [Ahí mismo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40037023/3281648) hay un ejemplo de cómo hacer una tarea programada pero por hora: `[Run]
Filename: "schtasks"; \
    Parameters: "/Create /F /SC HOURLY /TN ""My Task"" /TR ""'{app}\MyProg.exe' par1"""; \
    Flags: runhidden`